# How do I remove this symbol from the CSV file that is generated by Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv, puppeteer

When I generate the CSV file each "item" output comes out with a Â symbol. How would I go about removing this with my code. I tried to change it to utf-8 because I read that might be what's causing it. Any ideas? Example: [image]

```
const products = await page.$$('.item-row'); 

Promise.all(products.map(async product => {
// Inside of each product find product SKU, it's human-readable name, and it's price
let productId = await product.$eval(".custom-body-copy", el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g,' -').replace('Item  ', ''));
let productName = await product.$eval(".body-copy-link", el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g,' -'));
let productPrice = await product.$eval(".product_desc_txt div span", el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g,' -'));

// Format them as a csv line
return productId + ',' + productName + ',' + productPrice + ',';
})).then(lines => {
// Write the lines to a file
fs.writeFileSync("products.csv", lines.join('\n'), 'utf-8');
browser.close();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better solutions, but the first thing that comes to mind to to change the string to an array with `split()` and then `.map` through and test for the `Ã` ascii code and change back to a string with `join()` like this:

```
const strToChange = 'My string with an Ã char';

const charWeDoNotWant = 'Ã'.charCodeAt();

const toFixArr = strToChange.split('');

fixedArr = toFixArr.map(char =>
  char.charCodeAt() === charWeDoNotWant ? '' : char
);

const fixedStr = fixedArr.join('');
console.log(`String without Ã: ${fixedStr}`);
```

Comment: Here's what I did, I think the space was causing a weird character to appear: let productId = await product.$eval(".custom-body-copy", el => el.innerText.trim().replace(/,/g,' -').replace('Item', '').replace(/\s+/g, ''));